# Convert html input data to dynamic variable name

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that receives an HTML form. One of the form fields is a value chosen by the user. I need to convert this string value to a variable name.

I have the following variable that maps an SQL database:

```
private29_table = Base.classes.private29
```

The below variable uses an fstring to grab the user input and add "_table" to the end.

```
ip_table = f"{form_data['ip_quantity']}_table"
```

I then try to run an SQL query with the below code:

```
sql_session.query(ip_table).filter(ip_table.assigned_to == 
form_data['ip_quantity']).first()]
```

Let's say that the user inputs "private29" into the input form. ip_table becomes 'private29_table' but is a string type of course so I get an error when I try to run the code that string doesn't have method 'assigned_to'. Is there any way I can convert the string that ip_table comes back with to a valid variable name so the 'assigned_to' method actually targets the variable instead of the string?

The reason for this is that a user has 4 input options and each input option looks in a different mysql table. I'd like to tackle this query in as few lines of code as possible and not with if statements based on the value the user sends from the form.

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I've researched every dynamically generated variable name post I could find and as I'm new to python and programming in general I didn't find anything that I understood might be my solution.

Thanks

Comment: If you're new to python, then what you should have taken away from the dynamic variable posts you read is that it's considered bad practice and is almost never the right way to do what you're trying to do. Use a dict instead.

Comment: I have read some warnings about it but I'm not worried about them at the moment as the values are one of possible 4. Do dictionaries allow me to point a string value at an object with the same name as the value in the string? I can't see such an example anywhere

Comment: dicts allow you to resolve strings to objects, yes. Wherever you're currently defining the variables that you're trying to point `ip_table` to, define them as a dict instead.